# SQL Server - Conditionally Increment a Counter

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I'm looking to do is create grouped sequences for continuous date ranges. Take the following sample data:

```
Person|BeginDate |EndDate
A     |1/1/2015  |1/31/2015
A     |2/1/2015  |2/28/2015
A     |4/1/2015  |4/30/2015
A     |5/1/2015  |5/31/2015
B     |1/1/2015  |1/30/2015
B     |8/1/2015  |8/30/2015
B     |9/1/2015  |9/30/2015
```

If BeginDate in the current row is >1 day from the EndDate in the previous row then increment the counter by 1, otherwise assign the counter's current value. The sequencing would look like :

```
Person|BeginDate |EndDate  |Sequence
A     |1/1/2015  |1/31/2015|1
A     |2/1/2015  |2/28/2015|1
A     |4/1/2015  |4/30/2015|2
A     |5/1/2015  |5/31/2015|2
B     |1/1/2015  |1/30/2015|1
B     |8/1/2015  |8/30/2015|2
B     |9/1/2015  |9/30/2015|2
```

Partitioned and reset for each person.

For your testing :

```
 CREATE TABLE ##SequencingTest(
 Person char(1)
,BeginDate date
,EndDate date)

INSERT INTO ##SequencingTest
VALUES
('A','1/1/2015','1/31/2015')
,('A','2/1/2015','2/28/2015')
,('A','4/1/2015','4/30/2015')
,('A','5/1/2015','5/31/2015')
,('B','1/1/2015','1/30/2015')
,('B','8/15/2015','8/31/2015')
,('B','9/1/2015','9/30/2015')
```

Comment: Typically referred to as `islands and gaps` and plenty of solutions can be found by searching on that term.

Comment: way to include a schema and insert statement !  If only everyone did this

Comment: here is one good link :http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `lag()` and then a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(flag) over (partition by person order by begindate) as sequence
from (select t.*,
             (case when datediff(day, lag(endDate) over (partition by person order by begindate), begindate) < 2
                   then 0
                   else 1
              end) as flag
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Not sure if this method works. For Person A, row 2 increments to 2 instead of remaining 1. For Person B, their 2nd and 3rd rows each increment to 2 and 3

Comment: @idgt . . . The code is correct.  The last day of January is 2015-01-31, not 2015-01-30.

Comment: @idgt . . . I changed the logic to a `datediff()`.  I assumed you were looking for consecutive days, but `> 1` clearly allows an extra day in between.

Comment: Well that was a stupid error on my part! Really smart approach. I had no idea you could use the OVER clause with sum. Well done.

Comment: @idgt . . . You actually prefer the other answer to this one?  This is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If the continuous end dates are always 1 day before the next start date you could do something really primitive like this:

```
SELECT S1.Person, S1.BeginDate, S1.EndDate, SUM(S2.Cntr) AS Sequence
FROM Sequencing S1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Person, BeginDate,
      CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Person FROM Sequencing S2 WHERE S2.[EndDate] =
            DATEADD(d, -1, S1.[BeginDate]) AND S2.Person = S1.Person) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Cntr
      FROM [Sequencing] S1
     ) S2
  ON S1.Person = S2.Person
  AND S1.BeginDate >= S2.BeginDate
GROUP BY S1.Person, S1.BeginDate, S1.EndDate
ORDER BY S1.Person, S1.BeginDate, S1.EndDate
```

Note I think you meant to say '1/31/2015' and '8/31/2015' as end dates to work with your example.

Also, @GordonLinoff's answer is probably better.  I simply do not have the version of SQL Server to test it with.

Comment: This method also appears to work well! Thanks for that.